# LIMIT by GROUPED field instead of all rows returned

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm using this (simplified):

```
SELECT
o.order,
GROUP_CONCAT(oi.article)
FROM orders o
JOIN order_items oi
ON o.order = oi.order
GROUP BY o.order
LIMIT 50
```

to get the last 50 orders with all order items.

But I need the order items to be in their own rows (veritcally returned) instead of GROUP_CONCAT horizontally returned.

How can I return all order items of the last 50 orders with a single order item in each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to select the last 50 orders, and then join this with the items.

```
select o.order, oi.article
from (SELECT order
      FROM orders
      ORDER BY order_date DESC
      LIMIT 50) o
JOIN order_items oi
ON o.order = oi.order
```

Answer (score 1):

You talk about the last 50 items, but you don't mention a date_field to ORDER BY. Having that date_field in orders table you can do:

```
SELECT o.order, oi.article
FROM (SELECT order
      FROM orders
      ORDER BY date_field DESC
      LIMIT 50 ) o
INNER JOIN order_items oi ON o.order = oi.order
```